Partial derivatives of this function: it does exist but it doesn't.
I don't understand why I'm getting two different results about the existence of the partial derivative wrt $x$ of this function :
$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^2+2y}{x^2+y^2} & (x, y) \neq (0, 0) \\\\ 0 & (x, y) = (0, 0) \end{cases}$$
First method
$f(x, 0) = 1 \implies f'_x(x, 0) = 0$ hence $f'_x(0, 0) = 0$
It does exist.
Second method
$$f'_x(0, 0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(0+h, 0) - f(0, 0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h}\cdot \frac{h^2}{h^2} \to \pm \infty$$
It does not exist.
Can you help me?

$f(x,0)=1$ for all $x$ is clearly not true.

@geetha290krm Why? Even if $f(0, 0) = 0$ this doesn't tell me anything because $x$ is free. Hence $f(x, 0) = \frac{x^2}{x^2} = 1$, the limit applies later. I mean $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x, 0) = \lim_{x\to 0} 1 = 1$

You're making the assumption that $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x) = g(0)$ where $g$ is the partial derivative you are calculating, which you are treating like a basic property of functions. This is not true for functions, only for continuous ones. The wrong assumption is you are making is that the partial derivative is continuous.

Your title could "to be or not to be ?":)

The function $f$ is not continuous at the origin. To check for this, just consider
$$f(x, x) = \frac{x^2+x}{3x^2}$$
Which doesn't go to zero when $x \to 0$.
(Note: even if is did go to zero that wouldn't constitute a proof for continuity at the origin).
Because of this, what you wrote in the comment is not valid, since as @Ninad pointed out, you can only state that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = f(0)$ if $f$ is continuous at $0$, which here is not the case.
Also, even the partial derivative is not continuous at $(0, 0)$, so the same speech holds.
In the end, $f(x, 0) = 1$ if $x \neq 0$, otherwise it's $0$. Because of this, the first method is wrong.
The second one you used is correct and it points out rather easily that there is no derivative wrt $x$ at $(0, 0)$.

Notice that $f(x,0)=0$ when $x$ is $0$, so your method $1$ does not work. See this example:
$g(x)=\begin{cases} 0, &\text{if $x$ is $0$} \\
1, &\text{if $x$ $\neq0$ }\end{cases}$
$g'(0)=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}=\infty$

why downvote ...
